# PyQt Qwebengineview cannot zoom online pdf

Tags: python, qt, pdf, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I use qwebengineview to load web with simple code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings

class WebPreview(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebPreview, self).__init__(parent)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)

    def preview(self, link):
        self.load(QUrl(link))
```

My problem is, when loading an online pdf, such as https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-021-00506-8.pdf the page will become extremly small when I use ctrl+wheel to zoom

[image: check this link]

However, if I load any other none-pdf web https://www.google.com/ I can zoom perfectly with ctrl+wheel

system: windows 10
python: python 3.8
pyqt5: 5.15.3
pyqt5-webengine: 5.15.3

Comment: Zooming here is not done by the WebEngineView itself, but by PDF.js - and it must miss a parameter or something from WebEngineView to have the Zoom function correctly. I'm on exactly the same issue.

Comment: I just tried it out, in the most recent Qt Version (6.2.2), this issue seems "fixed". Scrolling and Zooming in a PDF in WebEngineView still is quirky, but it is at least usable.

Answer (score -1):

This may work:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings

class WebPreview(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebPreview, self).__init__(parent)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.PluginsEnabled, True)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.PdfViewerEnabled, True)

    def preview(self, link):
        self.load(QUrl(link))
```

And also you can use pyside6.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineSettings
import sys

class WebPreview(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebPreview, self).__init__(parent)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.PluginsEnabled, True)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.PdfViewerEnabled, True)

    def preview(self, link):
        self.load(QUrl(link))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = WebPreview()
window.preview(r"https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-021-00506-8.pdf")
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5WHR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).